# OpenCL idle GPU after I/O

Tags: optimization, opencl, python-idle

I have a strange problem with an app that is running fine, but has some unreasoned performance lost. The app and code is private, but I can give here some detailed working mode of it (simplified a LOT).

My app uses 4 kernels:

```
 1. Preprocesses

  Reads "I" buffer; Writes to "T" buffer

 2. Process

  Reads + Writes "T" buffer

 3. Parse & Preprocess

 Reads + Writes "T" buffer,  & writes "O" buffer

 4. Check

  Reads "O" buffer; Writes to "C" buffer (result of Check)
```

All the buffers are saved into the device. "I" and "O" buffers are a 200kB buffer each one. "T" buffer is around 20MB and is never used outside the GPU. "C" buffer is just a 4byte int giving the result.

The system runs in 3 different forms:

```
 - Pure iterative: Write,1,2,3,2,3,2,3,.....,2,3,Read
 - Iterative + Reading intermediate: Write,1,2,3,Read,2,3,Read,2,3,.....,2,3,Read
 - Iterative + Check: Write,1,2,3,4,Read(C),2,3,4,Read(C),2,3,.....,2,3,Read
```

In the first mode all the kernels are queued at once, I have no problem with that mode, just runs at max GPU utilization(and CPU).
The other 2 modes use progressive queuing of kernels, if the read value is not correct a new set of kernels is queued.

However in the second and third modes, after each read from device the device remains idle for some time. I have profile the program, and there are small gaps (100us) of no GPU use time after each read. This does not happen after the write part.
I have created 2 separate queues for I/O and execution to enable parallelization, with no luck.

The gaps are like this (I could post a screen of Visual profiler tomorrow):

> - Write,1,2,3,Read,2,**GAP**,3,Read,2,**GAP**,3,.....,2,3,Read

This problem appears with HD5770, HD5570, GTX570, C2050, C2070 as far as I have tested. And in windows and linux. **But in Quadro 2000M just runs perfectly fine, even doing parallel kernel execution and I/O!!**

Is there something I have miss? Is pinned memory faster than manual clCreate + clWrite/Read? Could it solve this problem?
I realized that I can run the kernel 2 in that gap as many times as I want but is not possible to run the kernel 3, is the memory "O" somehow protected and blocking the kernel 3 from running??

PD: I have some clWaitForEvents in the modes that have a gap. I tested removing them and the gap decreased a little around 50%, but CPU usage increased from 20% to 100%. Could this had something to do with CPU, or scheduler/driver?